# Blogger Popular Post Widget by Label

Tags: javascript, html, json, label, blogger

it works fine but not the way I want it

This code is based on label but according to post upload, but what I want is popular post based on label not based on upload, what's with this code?

-- Widget Add

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var numposts = 6;
    var showpostthumbnails = true;
    var displaymore = false;
    var displayseparator = false;
    var showcommentnum = false;
    var showpostdate = false;
    var showpostsummary = false;
    var numchars = 0;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/LABEL?orderby=updated&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/LABEL?max-results=6&alt=json-in-script&callback=recentpostslist"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, labels show posts from new all the way to the oldest in their respective category, so I don't think you can show popular posts through labels in the way you're trying to show. I think you would need a separate script with custom functions to do it.

Comment: do you know the script?

can you tell me the script or is there some other way?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have the script. Did you get this idea, or did you see it in some blog? If it's the latter, then why don't you try asking them?

Comment: I am still a beginner at blogger, I take this script on blog and edit it as best I can, good idea to contact this script creator and thanks in advance